# How to find first <td> in table that contains a <p> element using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse the table located at this page http://www.bluenote.net/newyork/schedule/index.shtml. I am trying to get the start time and Band name of who is playing on the current today. I noticed that the first td that contains the p element in the table is what I'm looking for. Any idea how I would go about this? I tried using

```
soup.findAll("p")
```

but I am trying to select the entire "td" that contains that "p" element.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a generator:

```
first_td = next(td for td in soup.find_all('td') if td.p)
#               ^           generator                  ^
```

The `find_all` will yield all `<td>` tags. We then filter the tags by `td.p`. This will return the `p` tag (given there is one). Otherwise it will return `None`. Since the *truthiness* of `None` is `False` and for the tag objects it is `True`, the generator will thus enumerate all `<td>` tags with a `<p>` tag.

We call `next(..)` to obtain the first of these elements. In case no such element exists, it will raise a `StopIteration` exception.

In case you want *all* these tags, you can use list comprehension:

```
[td for td in soup.find_all('td') if td.p]
```

Comment: Thank you this worked great except it is returning every <td> tag that includes a p tag not just the first. Is there a way to put each td into an array?

Comment: @JackGruber: the generator will do that. But by calling the `next(..)` part you only get the first match.

Comment: I think I'm misunderstanding something, sorry. I called next, but is is still returning all of the tags, as if I didn't call next

Comment: @JackGruber: It should return the first `<td>` tag. The representation of a tag will generate the *outer* html. So it is possible you see additional `<p>` tags, etc. But you have a reference to the first `td` tag. What is in the tag, is something we don't care much about.

Comment: Aaah makes sense. Any idea how I would have it return each td element into an array?

Comment: @JackGruber: that's the last code fragment :) with list comprehension.